# Is the space of states in quantum mechanics really a Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

My question is about the transition from discrete to continuous quantum mechanics, which amounts to losing the restriction of bounded compact operators on a Hilbert space. When one introduces these kind of operators into quantum mechanics, tipically through the momentum and position operators, it is costumary to write things like $$|\psi\rangle=\int dx  \, \psi(x) |x\rangle$$
Of course the meaning of this being a superposition in some "continuous basis" is clear. What is not clear to me is the physical meaning of $|x\rangle$. Some sources (like Talagrand) identify this object with the Dirac delta distribution, so it surely is not in the Hilbert space. But then what is its physical meaning? Because if it can't be an eigenvector of any operator, then the usual rules of Hilbert space quantum mechanics don't apply, I would assume.

Also the fact that both a general state and these position or momentum kets are represented in ket notation makes me think that maybe there's a way of formulating quantum mechanics in which all these objects belong to the same space and have the same interpretation as physical states of a system. Is there?

To conclude, I'm asking if the real space of states for systems with observables of continuous spectra is still the Hilbert space; if not, what is? And if it is possible, I'd like to shed some light on the meaning of kets like the momentum and position.

Comment: It is a *rigged* Hilbert space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space

Comment: Does it matter? What experiment could distinguish this?

Comment: It does matter, as the eigenfunctions of the momentum operator (or the position operator, as you mentioned) are not properly square integrable. But they do form a useful basis of states in the rigged Hilbert space.

Comment: @MattHanson What experimental result depends on whether the eigenfunctions are properly square integrable?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can give things like $\lvert x\rangle$ a rigorous meaning via rigged Hilbert spaces. OTOH, you do not even need to introduce these, as you can formulate QM without them, e.g. via projection valued measures etc. The point is that these objects are, for physicists, quite useful and easy to handle (if one knows that he/she is doing), while formulating everything mathematically rigorous introduces a lot of complications.

Comment: To answer your direct question, it means that it is impossible for a system to be perfectly localized in a quantum sense. The measurable distribution of a particle must be finite in extent, which is a measurable phenomenon. This directly relates to the uncertainty principle and its practical consequences.

Comment: @MattHanson Irrelevant to experiment. Your position resolution is what it is, and sometimes modeling it with a delta function is perfectly sensible.

Comment: @MattHanson I'm not sure this is quite right, inasmuch as the uncertainty relations are for simultaneous measurements, not just for measurement of position alone.  Of course "the physics breaks down" if you localize too much because the wavepacket would involve a range of momenta and thus energies for which the non-relativistic framework of the SE is no longer valid, but that's not an issue with the uncertainly relation.

Comment: Do note that the fact that position and momentum eigenstates are Dirac delta distributions living in Rigged Hilbert space and not Hilbert space (but yet are still suitable bases to expand any function in the Hilbert space) is part of why we have to have renormalisation in QFT, but the discussion of quantum theory using Rigged Hilbert space is a dead end. ACuriousMind was pointing out that the rigorous treatment of quantum theory is via standard Hilbert space methods and limit taking, explaining why the Rigged Hilbert space stuff work, but not invoking them.